# Error running python's input function in RStudio

Tags: python-3.x, rstudio

Write a Python script in Rstudio, using the input function. Start running, after entering the data, press Enter and Rstudio still waits for input, that is, it cannot exit.

Comment: I have to use the Task Manager to quit RStudio because the console is always in keyboard input.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure that your question is specific. The way it is currently, it is neither clear what you tried, nor what the exact error is.

Comment: Enter the code in RStudio and run it：  >>>  x = input()     At this point you can enter the required content in the Console, but either way you can't exit the input() function (including pressing the Enter key, entering the newline, ESC). All I can do is to force RStudio to end.